# How to specify type of function who's parameter object has a key and allows any other keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

With typescript we are able to define an interface for an object that is required to have a key and may additional allow any other keys:

```
interface ObjectWithTrace {
  trace: string;
  [index: string]: any
}
const traced: ObjectWithTrace = { trace: 'x', foo: 'bar' }; // looks good
const untraced: ObjectWithTrace = { foo: 'bar' }; // Error: Property 'trace' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type 'ObjectWithTrace'. ts(2741)
```

In the above example, `trace` is the required key. We can add whatever keys we want to an object and as long the `trace` key is defined typescript is happy. Perfect

Now, when trying to extend this logic to apply to arguments of a function, an error occurs:

```
type FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: {
  trace: string;
  [index: string]: any
}) => any;
const doSomethingAndTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: { trace: string }) => {}; // looks good
const doSomethingElseAndTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: { trace: string, foo: 'bar' }) => {} /*
 Error: Type '(args: { trace: string; foo: "bar"; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'FunctionWithParamWithTrace'.
  Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ [index: string]: any; trace: string; }' but required in type '{ trace: string; foo: "bar"; }'.ts(2322)
*/
```

It seems like i'm missing something. Is there a way to define a type for a function that expects to only have on parameter - and have that parameter allow any keys with any values, while also requiring one key to exist specifically (e.g., a property called `trace`)?

What i'm hoping to support is the following:

```
const doSomethingWithTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: { trace: string, foo: string }) => {}; // looks good
const doSomethingWithoutTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: { foo: string }) => {} // Error: Property 'trace' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }'...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to be able to extends your wanted type by subtypes. This can be achieved by introducing of generic parameters:

```
type FunctionWithParamWithTrace<Args extends {
  trace: string;
  [index: string]: any
}> = (args: Args) => any;

const doSomethingAndTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace<{ trace: string }> 
= (args) => {}; // looks good
const doSomethingElseAndTrace: FunctionWithParamWithTrace<{ trace: string, foo: 'bar' }> 
= (args) => {} // works
```

The reason why you could not use more strict type as argument is visible in below code:

```
type FunctionWithParamWithTrace = (args: {
  trace: string;
  [index: string]: any
}) => any;

type FunctionWithMoreStrictParameters = (args: { trace: string, foo: string }) => any

type NoItDoesNotExtends 
= FunctionWithMoreStrictParameters extends FunctionWithParamWithTrace 
? true 
: false // false
```

It means your more strict function is not a subset of the original one therefor cannot be used as it. Why is that? Imagine you have function which works with more precise arguments, like function which always gets `foo`, this function cannot be used in replace of function which can take any object. That is why this cannot be performed.

---

Below some other example which will maybe tell more why using more strict argumented function is not a good idea and TS blocks such:

```
function f(arg: {a: string, b: string | number}) {
    return arg.b.concat('b cannot be used as string as it can be number') // error
}

function g(arg: {a: string, b: string}) {
    return arg.b.concat(' b can be used as string') // pass compilation
}
```

Function `g` argument type is a subset of function `f` argument type, therefor should be able to be used instead of `f`? Exactly opposite, function `f` can be used instead of `g` because it is able to work with wider type and it means it body need to perform additional checks. This is visible in function `f`, we cannot just use `string | number` as `string`, we need to perform additional checks of the value. But when we look at `g` it doesn't need to do checks as it works with `string` only. What then would happen if we would use `g` instead of `f` and we would get `number` argument, it would be of course runtime crash.

In summary function type is a subset of another function type if it more flexible in arguments types, not more strict.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without explicitly defining the generic parameters every time? I.e., to just define the function like one normally would and know that if it were passed in as a parameter to another function that required type `FunctionWithParamWithTrace` that it would satisfy the type criteria

Comment: The thing is that such funcion should not be passed as `FunctionWithParamWithTrace` as it will break the runtime. Check what I have added to the answer

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation - that makes a lot of sense